# Initialising an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm quite new to Cocoa and I am trying to setup a table view backed by an array. I've setup the app delegate as the datasource for the tableview, and implemented `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol.

When I run the app, I get the following log output:

> 2012-06-23 18:25:17.312 HelloWorldDesktop[315:903] to do list is nil
>   2012-06-23 18:25:17.314 HelloWorldDesktop[315:903] Number of rows is 0
>   2012-06-23 18:25:17.427 HelloWorldDesktop[315:903] App did finish
>   launching

I thought that when I called `reloadData` on the tableView it would call `numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView` again to refresh the view, but that doesn't seem to be happening. What have I missed?

My .h and .m listings are below.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource> 

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView * toDoListTableView;

@property (assign) NSArray * toDoList;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate 

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize toDoList; 
@synthesize toDoListTableView;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.toDoList dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"App did finish launching");
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
  //  toDoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    toDoList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2", nil];
    [self.toDoListTableView reloadData];
   // NSLog(@"table view %@", self.toDoListTableView);

}

//check toDoList initialised before we try and return the size
- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSInteger count = 0;
    if(self.toDoList){
        count = [toDoList count];
    } else{
        NSLog(@"to do list is nil");
    }
    NSLog(@"Number of rows is %ld", count);
    return count;
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSLog(@"in objectValueForTable");
    id returnVal = nil;

    NSString * colId = [tableColumn identifier];

    NSString * item = [self.toDoList objectAtIndex:row];

    if([colId isEqualToString:@"toDoCol"]){
        returnVal = item;
    } 

    return returnVal;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I'd check is that you're NSTableView IBOutlet is still set in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

```
NSLog(@"self.toDoListTableView: %@", self.toDoListTableView)
```

You should see output like:

```
<NSTableView: 0x178941a60>
```

if the outlet is set properly.

If you see 'nil' rather than an object, double check to ensure that your NSTableView is connected to your outlet in the XIB editing mode of Xcode.  Here's a [documentation link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html) for assistance connecting outlets.

Comment: OK I've added the log for the outlet in applicaitonDidFinishLaunching and it's nil by that point which explains why I don't see any data. But why would it be nil?

Comment: On closer inspection self.toDoListTableView is always nil, even in the  numberOfRowsInTableView method when that is called at the start. I guess it's not wired up as an outlet correctly?

Comment: I think it's because you've set the IBOutlet to assign and not weak or unsafe_unretained.

Comment: unsafe_unretained doesn't make any difference, and when I try weak I get this error: error: @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode [3]

Comment: Ok- now I see that you're not using ARC at all.  Why not?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS 10.6.8 - I thought it wasn't available til 10.7?

Comment: Makes sense.  I added some more information to my answer that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - I'd set the appDelegate as the datasource and the delegate for the tableView but ctrl-dragging from the tableView to the appDelegate, but I hadn't ctrl-dragged the other way to actually link up the outlet I'd declared with the table view. It's working now. Thanks for your help though Jeff.